# $q.all not catch resolved sending requests array?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using $q.all to send array of promise of request, some time it's work correctly and return to .then() , but other time for the same code and the same scenario $q.all after send request ( also request correct implement ) but not return to .then().

i'm using angularjs 1.5.3

```
       requests = requests.map((request) => { return request.submit();

        $q.all(requests).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(()=>{
       }).finally(()=>{});
```

Comment: Why the .catch() part? "return request.submit()" isn't enough?

Comment: trying put catch to trying to fixed issues , but work , i will update question

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: What does the console tell?

Comment: the problem as i says , the $q.all working at some time for the same code that have problem , the request sending return  status return (200) but $q.all().then ,  not catch deferred.resolved.